# Is Allowing Full Disk Access to Safari Dangerous?

Tags: safari, security, privacy, web-browser, html

I have created a front-end tool for work using only HTML, CSS and Js.
I'm trying to have my coworkers simply open the html file in their own browsers, but the browser gives an error that requires Safari to gain Full Disk Access.

The error is : [image]

The known fix for this error page is by allowing Safari to have Full Disk Access.

However, my concern is : What are the potential dangers of allowing Safari to have Full Disk Access? If there are sensitive data on my computer, would it be wise to allow Full Disk Access to Safari?

Comment: What I have seen on internet is more about rhe page is using to much disk space no data access. So try to reduce its local data. Would be more secure as granting access to Safari : js scripts would be allowed to accès sensitive data = DANGER

Comment: Could the web page be served from a web server instead?

Comment: Or even a shared disk or sent via email to all - although a web server is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential dangers of allowing Safari to have Full Disk Access is that if the browser is somehow compromised by malware then it could more easily access your documents. Is that dangerous? - It really depends on your specific situation, your threat model, your risk assessment and how you value the data on your system.

Remember that just 5 years ago, everyone was basically running Safari with "Full Disk Access" enabled - as macOS did not have that sandboxing feature at the time. So it's not catastrophically dangerous for most.

If I were in your shoes I would reevaluate whether this is really the "known fix" for your issue. An easy way around all of this would be to ask your coworkers to copy your tool to the `Applications` folder on their Mac. It's basically an application, so why not put it there. That should avoid the issue with Safari.

Another fix would be to host the tool on a web server (or CDN).